# Logical error while running the program

Tags: java

I have tried to run the program with different values for totalofusage. However, the amount is always be 0.0. Please help.

```
package bill;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Name, Address;
        int accountnumber, currentmeterreading, pastmeterreading;
        double totalofusage;
        Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.println ("Please enter your account number:");
        accountnumber = read.nextInt();
        read.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Please enter your name:");
        Name = read.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Please enter your address");
        Address = read.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Please enter the current meter reading:");
        currentmeterreading = read.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Please enter past meter reading");
        pastmeterreading = read.nextInt();


        totalofusage = currentmeterreading - pastmeterreading;

        System.out.println ("Account number:"+ accountnumber);
        System.out.println ("Current meter reading:"+ currentmeterreading);
        System.out.println ("Past meter reading:"+ pastmeterreading);
        System.out.println ("Name:"+ Name);
        System.out.println ("Address:"+ Address);
        System.out.println ("Usage:" + totalofusage);

        Calculate searchbill = new Calculate();
        searchbill.calculateBill();

}}
```

```
package bill;

public class Calculate { 

double  totalofusage, amount;




    public void calculateBill (){

        if ((totalofusage > 0) && (totalofusage <= 200))
            amount = totalofusage * 0.218;
        else if ((totalofusage > 200) && (totalofusage <=300))
            amount = totalofusage * 0.334;
        else if ((totalofusage >300) && (totalofusage <= 400))
            amount = totalofusage * 0.400;
        else 
            amount = totalofusage * 0.402;

        System.out.println ("Amount ="+ amount);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you should read the whole line, not next int.  It's the end of line whitespace that's killing you.

Comment: Add some debugging statements that print out each quantity you read in so you can see what your code is actually doing. That'll help you narrow down the error.

Comment: well, what exactly do you think 0 * anyValue will result in? it's quite normal that it always returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Calculate` class to this:

```
public class Calculate {
  public void calculateBill (double totalofusage) {
    double amount;

    if ((totalofusage > 0) && (totalofusage <= 200))
        amount = totalofusage * 0.218;
    else if ((totalofusage > 200) && (totalofusage <=300))
        amount = totalofusage * 0.334;
    else if ((totalofusage >300) && (totalofusage <= 400))
       amount = totalofusage * 0.400;
    else 
       amount = totalofusage * 0.402;

    System.out.println ("Amount ="+ amount);
}
```

And call it thus:

```
searchbill.calculateBill(totalofusage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Calculate {

double totalofusage, amount;

public void calculateBill (){

    if ((totalofusage > 0) && (totalofusage <= 200))
        amount = totalofusage * 0.218;
    else if ((totalofusage > 200) && (totalofusage <=300))
        amount = totalofusage * 0.334;
    else if ((totalofusage >300) && (totalofusage <= 400))
        amount = totalofusage * 0.400;
    else 
        amount = totalofusage * 0.402;

    System.out.println ("Amount ="+ amount);
}
```

here you have an instance variable totalofusage, which has the default value 0.
so, no matter how many times you call this calculate method, it will always end up doing:

```
amount = totalofusage * 0.402;
```

0 * 0.402 is indeed 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is basically a single problem in your program. You are using 2 classes `Bill` and `Calculate`. When you prompt the user to enter the data, you are storing the data in the local variables of class `Bill`. Now after the user entered all data, you calculate the variable `totalofusage` and store in the `Bill` class `totalofusage` variable. But this variable is not the same as the `totalofusage` variable of `Calculate` class. Which stays at 0.0. So when you call `searchbill.calculateBill();` the `totalofusage` is taken from the local variable of the `Calculate` class which is 0.0. So as a result you get amount as `0.0`.

To over come this problem you have to transfer the amount stored in `totalofusage` of the `Bill` class to the `totalofusage` of the `Calculate` class. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. after you calculate the `totalofusage` in `Bill` class set the value to the `Calculate` class. like this:

   ```
     Calculate searchbill = new Calculate();
     searchbill.totalofusage = totalofusage;
     searchbill.calculateBill();
   ```
2. passing as parameter to the method `calculateBill()` and change the `calculateBill` method appropriately as shown:

   ```
     //IN CLASS Bill
     Calculate searchbill = new Calculate();
     searchbill.calculateBill(totalofusage);

     //IN CLASS Calculate
     public void calculateBill (double totalofusage){
        this.totalofusage = totalofusage
        //Remaining code
        ....
     }
   ```

Comment: Thank you sir for your explanation, i am a newbie in programming.
I have few questions sir.

1)  why we should used this "searchbill.totalofusage = totalofusage;" other than "searchbill.totalofusage();

2) When should i put in parameter like (double totalofusage)

Comment: @Cck `searchbill.totalofusage = totalofusage;` can also be written as `searchbill.totalofusage = this.totalofusage;` means that the variable `totalofusage` in the variable `searchbill` is assigned what is stored in this instance of `Bill`'s `totalofusage`.

Comment: @Cck  2nd case we are not setting the `searchbill`'s `totalofusage` variable. instead we are sending the value stored in `totalofusage` variable of this instance of `Bill` class. Now in the `Calculate` class's `calculateBill` method takes the value that was sent and stores it in a variable `totalofusage` then in the first line of the method, `this.totalofusage = totalofusage;` this actually assigns the value of the function's parameter `totalofusage` to this instance of `Calculate`  class's `totalofusage` instance variable.